# Slim Python Dockerfile not executing

Tags: python, docker

I created a slim docker file for my app:

```
FROM python:3.7-slim-stretch AS build
RUN python3 -m venv /venv

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get upgrade -y && \
    apt-get install -y git && \
    apt-get install -y build-essential && \
    rm -rf /var/cache/apt/* /var/lib/apt/lists/*

ADD ./requirements.txt /project/
RUN /venv/bin/pip install -r /project/requirements.txt

ADD . /project
RUN /venv/bin/pip install /project
WORKDIR /project

FROM python:3.7-slim-stretch AS production
COPY --from=build /venv /venv
CMD ["/venv/bin/python3","-m", "myapp"]
```

The docker is building and working. The running python executable is copied from the build image. (Verified, if I remove "/venv/bin" it won't run).
 However, to save some space I want to change my production base docker to:

`FROM debian:stretch-slim`

But then I'm getting an error:

```
docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:345: starting container process caused "exec: \"/venv/bin/python3\": stat /venv/bin/python3: no such file or directory": unknown.
```

Now, I don't understand this error. I can see the python executable is there, why he wouldn't run? Whats in the base python docker image allow it to run?

Comment: Maybe you have to just install python3 manually in your dockerfile =)

Comment: But why? The executable already found in venv (I can see it).

Comment: try to replace the python command by a sleep, go into the container with a docker exec -it [container-name] /bin/bash and run manally python3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go in your `venv` in your container and `ls -l` the bin directory.

`lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   21 Dec  4 17:28 python -> /usr/local/bin/python`

Yes `python` is there but it is a symlink to a file which does not exists.

You can go around this first problem by using `RUN python3 -m venv --copies /venv` in your Dockerfile.

But you will then hit the following error message:

> error while loading shared libraries: libpython3.7m.so.1.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

So you will finally need to install the exact same version of python in your image as the one available at build time.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer!

Is there a way for my production docker to be slimmer? For example, install Python without pip?

Comment: You mean like `apt install python3` in a `debian:stretch-slim` image ?

Comment: Still getting the error, even when adding it to the path ENV PATH="/venv/bin:$PATH"
(And running apt-get python3)

Comment: Did you use the --copies options during build ? Are you using the exact same version of python in both build and run image ? If you kept your current build image, it is probably not the case.